# SQLite3 foreign key mismatch

Tags: sqlite

I have following `SQLite3` statement inside `Qt/C++` class method:

```
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString& address,
                                const QString& port,
                                const QString& dbName,
                                const QString& dbUsername,
                                const QString& dbPassword,
                                const QString& hostName,
                                const QString& autoStockUpdate,
                                const QString& topN,
                                const QString& autoLogoffWorkerAtBill/*,
                                UeTypePrintersList* const printersList*/)
{
    bool result=false;
    bool connected=false;

    if(this->ueDatabase().isOpen())
    {
        connected=true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->ueConnectToDatabase())
        {
            connected=this->ueDatabase().open();
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << this->ueDatabase().lastError().text();
        }   // if
    }   // if

    if(connected)
    {
        QSqlQuery querySaveSettings(UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::QUERY_SAVE_SETTINGS.arg(address)
                                                                                            .arg(port)
                                                                                            .arg(dbName)
                                                                                            .arg(dbUsername)
                                                                                            .arg(dbPassword)
                                                                                            .arg(hostName)
                                                                                            .arg(autoStockUpdate)
                                                                                            .arg(topN)
                                                                                            .arg(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString())
                                                                                            .arg(autoLogoffWorkerAtBill),
                                    this->ueDatabase());


        if(querySaveSettings.lastError().isValid())
        {
            qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                     << querySaveSettings.lastError().text();
        }
        else
        {
            this->ueSetServerAddress(address);
            this->ueSetServerPort(port);
            this->ueSetDatabaseName(dbName);
            this->ueSetDatabaseUsername(dbUsername);
            this->ueSetDatabasePassword(dbPassword);
            this->ueSetHostname(hostName);
            this->ueSetAutomaticStockUpdateFromFirstWarehouse(autoStockUpdate=="1"?true:false);
            this->ueSetNumberOfTopSalesProductsShown(topN);
            this->ueSetAutoLogoffWorkerAtBill(autoLogoffWorkerAtBill=="1"?true:false);

            for(int printerIndex=0; printerIndex<this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->size(); printerIndex++)
            {
                QString querySavePrintersCommand=UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::QUERY_SAVE_PRINTERS.arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterName())
                                                                                                         .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterAddress())
                                                                                                         .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterLocation())
                                                                                                         .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsKitchenPrinter())
                                                                                                         .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsReceiptPrinter())
                                                                                                         .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsReportPrinter());
                QSqlQuery querySavePrinters(querySavePrintersCommand,
                                            this->ueDatabase());
                if(querySavePrinters.lastError().isValid())
                {
                    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                             << querySavePrinters.lastQuery()
                             << querySavePrinters.lastError().text();
                }
                else
                {
                    result=true;
                }   // if
            }   // for

            emit this->ueSignalSettingsSaved();
        }   // if
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // ueSaveSettings
```

Now, I want to save printer(s) settings into `SQLITE3` database, in table named 'PRINTERS' this task should be executed in following statement of upper code:

```
for(int printerIndex=0; printerIndex<this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->size(); printerIndex++)
{
    QString querySavePrintersCommand=UeApplicationSettings::UeSqlQueries::QUERY_SAVE_PRINTERS.arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterName())
                                                                                             .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterAddress())
                                                                                             .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->uePrinterLocation())
                                                                                             .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsKitchenPrinter())
                                                                                             .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsReceiptPrinter())
                                                                                             .arg(this->uePrintersModel()->uePrintersList()->at(printerIndex)->ueIsReportPrinter());
    QSqlQuery querySavePrinters(querySavePrintersCommand,
                                this->ueDatabase());
    if(querySavePrinters.lastError().isValid())
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
                 << querySavePrinters.lastQuery()
                 << querySavePrinters.lastError().text();
    }
    else
    {
        result=true;
    }   // if
}   // for
```

Instead of saving printer data to database, I get following `qDebug()` output - **`SQLITE3` error**:

```
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&) "INSERT INTO PRINTERS (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, LOCATION, ISKITCHEN, ISRECEIPT, ISREPORT) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), \"Canon-MP280\", \"\", \"\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\");" "foreign key mismatch - \"PRINTERS\" referencing \"SETTINGS\" Unable to execute statement"
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&) "INSERT INTO PRINTERS (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, LOCATION, ISKITCHEN, ISRECEIPT, ISREPORT) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), \"PDF\", \"\", \"\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\");" "foreign key mismatch - \"PRINTERS\" referencing \"SETTINGS\" Unable to execute statement"
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&) "INSERT INTO PRINTERS (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, LOCATION, ISKITCHEN, ISRECEIPT, ISREPORT) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), \"POS58\", \"\", \"\", \"1\", \"1\", \"0\");" "foreign key mismatch - \"PRINTERS\" referencing \"SETTINGS\" Unable to execute statement"
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&) "INSERT INTO PRINTERS (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, LOCATION, ISKITCHEN, ISRECEIPT, ISREPORT) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), \"POS80\", \"\", \"\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\");" "foreign key mismatch - \"PRINTERS\" referencing \"SETTINGS\" Unable to execute statement"
bool UeSettings::ueSaveSettings(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&) "INSERT INTO PRINTERS (ID, NAME, ADDRESS, LOCATION, ISKITCHEN, ISRECEIPT, ISREPORT) VALUES (last_insert_rowid(), \"TS-M210-087\", \"\", \"\", \"0\", \"0\", \"0\");" "foreign key mismatch - \"PRINTERS\" referencing \"SETTINGS\" Unable to execute statement"
```

Here is also **settings database layout**, I mean, with following script I create database at runtime (if it does not exists):

```
static const QString QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_SETTINGS="CREATE TABLE "+UeApplicationSettings::UeDatabase::SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME+
                                           " (ME_TIMESTAMP_REMOVED TEXT, ME_TIMESTAMP_ADDED TEXT, SETTINGS_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                                           "ST_AUTOUPDATE NUMERIC, GE_HOSTNAME TEXT, DB_SERVER_ADDRESS TEXT, DB_SERVER_PORT TEXT, "
                                           "DB_NAME TEXT, DB_USERNAME TEXT, DB_PASSWORD TEXT, GE_TOP_N TEXT,"
                                           "GE_AUTOLOGOFF_WORKER_AT_BILL INTEGER, PE_ID_PRINTERSETTINGS INTEGER); ";
static const QString QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_PRINTERS="CREATE TABLE "+UeApplicationSettings::UeDatabase::PRINTERS_TABLE_NAME+
                                           " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, ISKITCHEN INTEGER, "
                                           "ISRECEIPT INTEGER, ISREPORT INTEGER, "
                                           "FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES "+UeApplicationSettings::UeDatabase::SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME+"(PE_ID_PRINTERSETTINGS));";
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I get rid of it?

P.S.: I wanted to post this question to general SO site, but I think it is database related since the code itself compiles just fine.

And while opening connection to it, I also issue (first) command to [enable foreign key support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable):

```
static const QString QUERY_TURN_ON_FOREIGN_KEYS_SUPPORT="PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;";
```

Comment: BTW, are you sure that the foreign key constraint shouldn't be reserved?

Comment: @CL. what do you mean by **reserverd**?

Comment: Sorry, reversed. Is the relation 1:N or N:1?

Comment: @CL. relation is `1 (SETTINGS) to N (PRINTERS)`, at least I think it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last_insert_rowid()` returns the `rowid` of the most recently executed `INSERT` statement in the same connection, which is not what you want.

You have to use the ID of the setting that you want to refer to.

Also, as [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes), the `PE_ID_PRINTERSETTINGS` column needs to be the primary key, or have a UNIQUE constraint.